# Display form field depending on multiple answers

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am creating a sign up form and have created hidden fields that only display depending on the value chosen. The problem is I can't work out how to show the field based on multiple values chosen.

For example: Let's say one of the questions has a dropdown menu with possible answers A,B,C or D, I understand how to get the hidden field to show if ONE of the answers is selected but cannot get it to show if they choose A OR B.

Here is my code, I hope it shows what I am trying to do:

```
     $fields[] = new PMProRH_Field(
    "ahpraregistration",
    "text",
    array(  
    "depends"=>array(array('id' => "regsitrationlevel", 'value' => "holdslimited"||"holdsprovisional")),
            "label"=>"Please Provide Your AHPRA Registration Number",
            'required' => true,
            )
   ));
```

In this case, I want a text box to appear if 'holdslimited' OR 'holdsprovisional' is selected, currently it will only work if I use one value. What format do I need to use? How can I make this happen? Thank you!

Comment: what you have now is like a condition `'value' => "holdslimited"||"holdsprovisional"` or `'value'=>1`  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eae9808b28304741447a403a306238a1a93671fd)  because at least one of the strings are truthy,  the result is `1` of the condition.   You can test this by `'value' => 0||0`  - which returns `False` or empty [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6c6bc8a59fe24599d99255e7c21b6968b4bed82)

Comment: As for how to do this, well I never heard of this `PMProRH_Field` thing, but there is noting stopping you from doing it with JavaScript (I'll use Jquery),  `if($('input[name="ahpraregistration"]).val() == 'holdslimited') //do something`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason some simple jQuery wouldn't do the trick.

```js
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){

      function togglefield(){
          if($('select[name="foo"]').val() == 'holdsprovisional'){
              $('input[name="bar"]').css('display','');
          }else{
              $('input[name="bar"]').css('display','none');
          }
      }


      $('select[name="foo"]').change(function(){
          togglefield();
      });
      togglefield();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="foo" >
  <option value="holdslimited" >holdslimited</option>
  <option value="holdsprovisional" >holdsprovisional</option>
</select><br>
<input name="bar" />
```

The question is to broad for me to do more, you can obviously do the JS better, this was just to show it's pretty easy to hide or show a field.